# Is there a way to make a AHK that left clicks, then holds right click for 30 seconds and repeats?

Tags: autohotkey

I was curious if its possible to make a AHK script to left click once, then hold right click for 30 seconds and then loop but be toggled on a bind. Here's what i've tried:

```
F1::
     {
     Click Left
     Sleep, 10
     }

     {
     Click Right
     Sleep, 10
     }
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, I also added functionality such that it will release the RMB when you toggle it off so that the Right Mouse Button will not be stuck in a held-down state.

```
*F1::
toggle^=1
if(toggle){
    gosub, start
}else{
    SetTimer, release, Off
    gosub, release
}
return

start:
    if(toggle){
        Click
        Click, Right, Down
        SetTimer, release, -30000
    }
return


release:
    Click, Right, Up
    if(toggle){
        gosub, start
    }
return
```

Edit: Added Wildcard modifier

Edit 2: Fixed faulty logic/ bug in the script

Comment: @InfaRed Currently, just clicking F1 button while having no modifier keys (i.e. Cntrl, Alt, etc.) held down. If you need it to function with modifiers held down, just let me know and I can edit the script.

Comment: yes please, I don't really understand how it works and you've been a big help. btw does it toggle like if I hit F1 again does it toggle off?

Comment: I found a bug in the script that caused the program to function improperly, so I fixed that @InfaRed. If it wasn't working when you tried it earlier, it should work now. To answer your question, the script does toggle between an "On" state and an "Off" state when you press the F1 key on your keyboard.